# The closure of infinite union is not a subset of infinite union of closure

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

The following statement is supposed to be disproven:

$\overline{\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_{i}} \subset \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \overline{A_{i}}$

But I seem to be able to prove that the statement is true. What is wrong with the following reasoning?

If $x \in \overline{\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_{i}}$, then $x \in \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_{i}$ or $x \in \left(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_{i}\right)'$. Where ' denotes set of limit points. So consider the two cases.

If $x \in \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_{i}$ , then $x \in A_j$ for some j. So $x \in \overline A_j$, so $x \in \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \overline{A_{i}}$.

If $x \in \left(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_{i}\right)'$, then $\forall r>0, \exists z \in \left( \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_{i} \right) \cap B_r(x)$, and $z\neq x$. So $z \in A_j$ for some j. So $z \in \overline A_j$. That means $x$ is a limit point of $\overline A_j$. But $\overline A_j$ contains its limit points, so $x \in \overline A_j$. So $x \in \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \overline{A_{i}}$.

That proves $\overline{\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_{i}} \subset \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \overline{A_{i}}$.

Comment: Let $A_n=\{1/n\}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$z$ depends on $r.$ Different $r$ might give different $z$ and hence different $j,$ which could mean that the limit is not in any $\overline A_j.$

Hint:  Let $A_n=\left\{\frac{1}{n}\right\}.$

Answer (score 1):

Your $j$ depends on $z$. There need not be any particular $j$ such that $z \in A_j$ for all $z$ you choose in $(\bigcup A_i) \cap B_r(x)$. So $x$ need not belong to $\overline {A_j}$ for any $j$.

[The set of all rational numbers provides a counter-example for the equality you are trying to prove].